# Req.body empty whereas I tried all configuration

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I send a post request to my test url bu req.body is empty.
I'm using NodeJS, Express & the middleware BodyParser.

Here my code :

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();

});

app.post('/test/json/', function(req, res, next) {     
    res.json(req.body);
})
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.listen(8282);
```

In my req.body, it should disply {username:"Yacine"}

Please help me figure out with this cause I read all post looks like my problem & all solution provided are already used in my code.

Thanks

Comment: You should call the `app.use(bodyParser)` line first thing after `app=express()` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare middlewares before routes so you can use them, try to change like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
  Content-Type, Accept");
  next();

});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/test/json/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json(req.body);
});

app.listen(8282);
```

Comment: omg thanks a lot... I follow a tutorial that put this 2 lines at the end like I did...